# How to delete certain string from a csv file in java?

Tags: java

This is my csv file:

```
AP1234,Apple,iPhone5s,229.5,64,
AP6261,Apple,iPhone7,323.5,64,
SM9829,Samsung,GalaxyS7,555.0,64,
SM9230,Samsung,GalaxyS8,444.0,64,
SSSSS,Huawei,99C,1100.0,64,
```

Left to right:
`Serial Number, Brand, Model, Price, Memory`
Lets say I want to delete all the phones from samsung, how can I do this?

my code so far

```
    //Get phone by make
    public Phone getPhoneByMake(String make)
    {
        for(Phone p : this.PhoneList) {
            if(p.getMake().equals(make))
                return p;
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Delete all phones of certain make
    public void deleteAllMake(Phone p) {

        if(p == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Phone argument is null");
        PhoneList.remove(p);

    }
```

and in the main

```
try {
     Phone pl = pMgr.getPhoneByMake("Samsung");
     pMgr.deleteAllMake(pl);
    }catch (IllegalArgumentException exc) {
    }
```

Comment: The list `p` is empty, so it does not make any sense to remove something from it.

Comment: Use `!` in the `if` condition and `add()` instead of `remove()`

Comment: Suggestion: maybe use sqlite instead of just a CSV file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete all the specific models from csv file, you can read all the phones from file, filter phones and write them back. The minimal example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Phone> phones = readPhonesFromCSV("fileName.csv");
    String brandToDelete = "Samsung";
    List<Phone> filteredPhones = phones.stream()
            .filter(phone -> !phone.getBrand().equals(brandToDelete))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    writePhonesToCSV(filteredPhones);
}

public static List<Phone> readPhonesFromCSV(String fileName) {
    // Read logic...
}

public static void writePhonesToCSV(List<Phone> phones) {
    // Write logic...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) to remove all objects matching a given condition:

```
String make = "Huawei";
phones.removeIf(p -> p.getMake().equals(make));
```

This will remove all phones from the list which have *Huawei* as `make` attribute.

Comment: I used a different code just now, just updated to the new one. I first get the make and delete it, however it'll only delete the first phone with that model